# Passing the class name in the table whose object should be created

Tags: php

Can I pass the name of the class in the argument so that the function would create its object in PHP ?

```
class WebManager
{
    $item = null;

    public function set(array $param)
    {
        if ( (isset($_GET['c'])) || (empty($_GET['c'])) ) {

            foreach ($param as $key => $value) {
                if($key == $_GET['c']) {

                    $this->item = new $value; // ?? !!
                    break;
                }
            }

            if($this->item == null) {
                // unknow get param
                // load default
                $this->item = new Default();
            }
        } else {

            //load deafult
            $this->item = new Default();
        }
    }
}

$web = new WebManager();
$in = array('main'=>'', 'about'=>'', 'contact'=>'');
$web->set($in);
```

I have a page that has n-sub-pages each sub-page settles its class in which there are functions generating html code and a function that returns what styles and scripts JS needs a sub-page to load the main class.

Here the question arises: Is it a bad idea to include all definitions of these classes in the script with the main class?

class MainSubPage{...} <- file main-page.php

class AboutSubWebPage {...} <- file about.php

class ContactSubPage {...} <- file contact.php

And there is a separate file with the main / management class that appends all files with subpage classes with require. The only question that arises is why to include these files if only one is used anyway? Is this too much a desire for a certain idealism? And joining by only require class definitions is not a burden or a server clutter?

Comment: i'm not really sure what is asked, as i don't see at first glance how the first and last questions are related (last question seems to be the one that matters imo). So the usual inclusion pattern is that each page includes its class file that corresponds (ex: class MainSubPage{...} <- file main-page.php), and each file class includes the main class which it extends (ex: file main-page.php <- file main-class.php). This way, everything loads just what it needs

Answer (score 0):

I did not write a precise question. There is a main class that contains one of these classes. At the moment, the main class file contains definitions of all classes that extend it. I asked the question because it seems to me that it is a bad practice for a file with the main class to always include class declarations that it will not use. So I needed the code:

```
function get(string $className, string $classFile)
{
    if (!file_exists($classFile)) {
        echo 'err !';
        return;
    }

    include($classFile);

    if(!class_exists($className)) {
        echo 'err !';
    }

    return new $className();    
}
```

But is joining a class declaration file correct? In this file, for example, I have a class MainSubPage {public function draw () {...} public function init () {...}} And something like that I include in the function. Does that not bother you?

Comment: The `get` function you wrote is pretty much close to wide-spread autoload implementations. It is perfectly valid to dedicate a function to including class definitions. PHP adopted this technique officially somewhere 15 years ago.

Comment: I've heard that I'm not going to add class declarations in a function using require but the code I presented reminds me of the MVC pattern, and in this pattern, the model and view classes are added using include in the function, right? In the case of MVC, I should add one model controller and several subpage views. The model loads different content for different widgets. Without it is adding a separate model for each view if the code of each model will be the same and the functionality of the model consists only in loading the content from the database. Truth ?

Answer (score 0):

In modern PHP using autoload functions is considered best practice. If you are new to this, please read on: http://php.net/autoload

Following PHP standards is also considered best practice. In this case this one is relevant: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Furthermore, with composer getting everywhere, provided you have SSH access to your development environment, I would recommend modernizing your codebase like follows.

DISCLAIMER. Some details of the further explanation are a matter of personal taste. You or other folks here may want to modify it according to your needs/tastes. Feel free to fix it, as it only serves as an example.

1. Create `src` directory for class definitions.
2. Put there each class's definition to a separate file with name matching the class name:

   ```
   class MainSubPage{...} <- file src/MainSubPage.php

   class AboutSubWebPage {...} <- file src/AboutSubWebPage.php

   class ContactSubPage {...} <- file src/ContactSubPage.php
   ```
3. Install composer from https://getcomposer.org/
4. Add a `composer.json` file to your document root with at least the following:

   ```
   {
       "autoload": {
           "psr-4": {
               "": "src/"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Run `composer install`. This will create a `vendor` directory under your document root.
6. In each entry-point php file (which your web server accesses directly) start with this line:

   ```
   // May have to add more ../'s to match file hierarchy.
   require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
   ```

This will teach your scripts how to get class definitions without you having to include their source files directly.

PS. There are some other benefits of using this pattern, like having instant access to a large quantity of ready-to-use modern site-building tools at packagist.org. You're not required to use them, but they are there in case you're interested.